# Parse JSON data which is a response to http get request

Tags: json, node.js

Using NODE.js I am trying to develop a website which sends request to some third-party server, and the response being in JSON format, what is the best way rather the fastest way to filter the data directly ? Suppose i want to query certain books of a specific author, what is the best practice ?

- Should i handle this in callback ? and then parse the entire response object ?
- OR Should i filter the response while receiving itself in the stream using pipe ?

NOTE that i am intending to develop a website which will have to answer users in real-time, so time is precious here.

Comment: Are you using Angular or you need to retrieve JSON data in server side code?

Comment: i need to retrieve in server side, and then pass the filtered data back to front-end.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use callback to retrieve JSON data and them use websocket to pass the filtered data to the client in real time.

http://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_http_get_options_callback

```
http.get("http://www.google.com/index.html", function(res) {
  console.log("Got response: " + res.statusCode);
}).on('error', function(e) {
  console.log("Got error: " + e.message);
});
```

You can use socket.io for node.js

http://socket.io/

Comment: Thanks for suggesting socket.io for realtime scenario. However regarding the callback, do you suggest thats the way we have to parse a JSON object. Point here is, we are not interested in entire object, nut only parts of its contents.

Comment: Maybe you don't have to parse JSON because I think it is inside `res` object as a JavaScript object, try with `console.log(res);` or with a debugger, in order to find the structure of `res` object.